# Have two CSS embedded languages style in web page for different text lang type

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am doing a multilingual website using HTML, CSS, PHP and JS, so the text might be in English or France according to user input as am pulling the data from DB.

Is there a way in CSS that automatically checks if the text is in English so it will apply the embedded English's font, and if its in France it will apply the embedded France's font.

if I previously know the language i would apply some CSS class to the text HTML element for example `<p class="en"></p>` or `<p class="fr"></p>`. But I don't know the language as the text coming from DB.

Comment: how do you know the language ? using php i guess ?

Comment: No, there is no way for CSS to automatically know what language text is. Why can't you use a specific css class? It only has to wrap all user generated content.

Comment: i agree but with @ReinerGerecke but if you can now what language with php (a get variable containing the value "en,fr,ar....." ) then i might have a solution for you

Comment: The language is called "French," not "France." :-) (Or arguably, the language is called *Français*.)

Comment: Sorry of bad English, but I don't know the language. But I know it should be English or France, if I previously know the language i would apply some CSS class to the text HTML element for example <p class="en"></p> or <p class="fr"></p>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no native way to do that with CSS, but your server presumably knows whether it's responding in English or in French. You can therefore do something like what Modernizr does and add a class to the `<html>` tag:

```
 <html class='french'>
```

Then you can have CSS rules that work based on that:

```
 .french body { font-family: YourFrenchFont, sans-serif; }
```

*edit* — Quentin's answer is similar but better since it uses a standard notation designed for this very purpose. However, this will work in older versions of IE, for those unfortunate enough to have to care.

Answer (score 8):

Browsers won't detect the language based on the text, but if you specify it using the correct markup:

```
<html lang="fr">
```

Then you can use [the language psuedo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#lang-pseudo):

```
html:lang(fr) {
    /* your rules */
}
```

Comment: Any idea how good the support is for that? As opposed to `html[lang=fr]` or using a class?

Comment: [CSS Tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/l/lang/) - `:lang(X) is a recommendation of the CSS Level 2 Revision 1 spec and orignally recommended as a part of the CSS Level 2 spec.`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder — I can't find any statistics for it, sadly, and it doesn't seem to be listed on caniuse

Comment: @misterManSam — huh, I didn't know it was in 2.1. Excellent.

Comment: People will also be interested in [IE Implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848867(v=vs.85).aspx) - `This pseudo-class requires that Windows Internet Explorer be in IE8 Standards mode or higher`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Note that the attribute selector won't work unless the attribute is explicitly set on the element. I wrote an answer explaining the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916360/whats-the-difference-between-htmllang-en-and-htmllangen-in-css/8916417#8916417