# What is the difference between E:dir(dir) and E[dir="dir"] in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

W3C is introducing a new pseudo-class for direction detection in Selectors 4. I am wondering what is the difference between that and a normal attribute selector:

**CSS2** - attribute selector

```
E[dir="rtl"] { ... }
```

**Selectors 4** - dir pseudo-class

```
E:dir(rtl) { ... }
```

Is there a specific reason for creating a new pseudo-class for that? Are these selectors identical or do they behave differently? Are there any performance or specificity implications?

Comment: The same reason why a :lang() pseudo exists as opposed to the [lang] attribute selector: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916360/whats-the-difference-between-htmllang-en-and-htmllangen-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:dir), some subtle differences exist:

> The :dir CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on the directionality
>   of the text contained in it. In HTML, the direction is determined by
>   the dir attribute. For other document types there may be other
>   document methods for determining the language.
>
> Note that the usage of the pseudo-class :dir() is not equivalent of
>   using the [dir=…] attribute selectors. The latter matches a value of
>   the dir and doesn't match when no attribute is set, even if in that
>   case the element inherits the value of its parent; similarly [dir=rtl]
>   or [dir=ltr] won't match the auto value that can be used on the dir
>   attribute. In the opposite, :dir() will match the value calculated by
>   the UA, being inherited or the auto value.
>
> Also :dir() considers only the semantic value of the directionality,
>   the one defined in the document, most of the time in HTML. It won't
>   consider styling directionality, the one set by CSS properties like
>   direction which are purely stylistic.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a specific reason for creating a new pseudo-class for that?

The same reason the `:lang()` pseudo-class was introduced alongside attribute selectors in CSS2.<sup>1</sup> See [What's the difference between html[lang="en"] and html:lang(en) in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916360/whats-the-difference-between-htmllang-en-and-htmllangen-in-css)

> Are these selectors identical or do they behave differently?

See my answer to the linked question. Here's the relevant quotation from [Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-dir-pseudo) for the sake of completeness:

> The difference between :dir(C) and ''[dir=C]'' is that ''[dir=C]'' only performs a comparison against a given attribute on the element, while the :dir(C) pseudo-class uses the UAs knowledge of the document’s semantics to perform the comparison. For example, in HTML, the directionality of an element inherits so that a child without a dir attribute will have the same directionality as its closest ancestor with a valid dir attribute. As another example, in HTML, an element that matches ''[dir=auto]'' will match either :dir(ltr) or :dir(rtl) depending on the resolved directionality of the elements as determined by its contents. [HTML5]

To drive the point home on the similarities between `:dir()` and `:lang()`, if you look closely the first sentence is in fact a *word-for-word copy* of the same paragraph in the section describing `:lang()`.

Much of the rest of the text for `:lang()` is new, however, because along with `:dir()`, Selectors 4 also introduces enhanced functionality for `:lang()`.

> Are there any performance or specificity implications?

Since the answer to your previous question is that they behave differently, performance is irrelevant.

No specificity implications because pseudo-classes and attribute selectors are equally specific.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>It's not clear to me why it took almost 15 years for `:dir()` to be added to Selectors, but there you go.</sub>