# Property " " must be followed by a ':'

Tags: css, scss-mixins

When i am compiled my style.scss file then compiler through error following

> `Property " " must be followed by a ':'`

When i have add following css is `style.scss` file then getting error

```
.custom-file-input:lang(en)~.custom-file-label::after {
   content: "Browse";
   padding: 8px 20px;
   height: 35px;
}
.custom-file label {
   width: 100%;
   height: 37px;
   padding: 8px 15px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try spaces around the ~ combinator?

Comment: I'm confused by the `:lang` – what's that doing? I know attribute selectors, which are used like this `[lang=en]`

Comment: @Andy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916360/whats-the-difference-between-htmllang-en-and-htmllangen-in-css

Comment: This snippet by itself doesn't reproduce errors on SassMeister. What version of Sass are you using?

Comment: Hi Andy thanks for quick reply I  have try with space also but didn't work

Comment: Hi Boltclock I am using Angular 7 that have by default scss setup

Comment: I am also struggling 3 hours for these issue but didn't find solution for it

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error in JS Fiddle, SassMeister, or CodePen -- but my educated guess is that whatever version of Sass your running and/or the compiler is getting caught  up on the `:lang(en)`. Does converting that to an attribute selector help? 

(It would be `.custom-file-input[lang="en"]` instead of `.custom-file-input:lang(en)`.)

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem when i had a mistake in naming my sass file. Now i understand that that issue stems from a sass syntax error or wrong filename imports